# opengl strange output from normalmap

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, normals

I create a terrain grid with 1024x1024 points, generate a normal map from that and try to use it in my vertex/fragment shader. Im getting strange results when i draw normals from normalmap compared to normals passed from the vertex shader. I try to improve quality by increase the texture resolution up to 8192, but doesnt remove strange aliasing effect.
The same happens when i get the normal from neighbouring pixels in a heightmap.
How can i fix this?

normalmap texture creation:

```
uint16_t channels = 3;
GLuint Texture = m_frameBuffers;
float* pData = new float[width * height * channels];

glGenTextures(1, &Texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture);

for (uint16_t y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    for (uint16_t x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
        uint32_t index = y * width + x;
        pData[index * channels + 0] = (normals[index].x) * 0.5 + 0.5;
        pData[index * channels + 1] = (normals[index].y) * 0.5 + 0.5;
        pData[index * channels + 2] = (normals[index].z) * 0.5 + 0.5;
    }
}
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pData);

glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);

delete[] pData;

++m_frameBuffers;
return Texture;
```

fragment shader:

```
vec3 normal = texture(normalMap, VertexIn.texcoord).rgb;
normal = normalize(normal * 2.0 - 1.0); 
normal = normalize(vec3(normalmatrix*vec4(normal,1.0)));
```

[image: normal from vertex]

[image: normal from normal map]

edit: i uploaded better pictures to compare. it shows same area of a 1024x1024 grid, first is from vertex normals, second uses normal map with RGB16F

Comment: The internal format of the normal map texture is `GL_RGB`. Try `GL_RGB16_SNORM` or `GL_RGB16F`. See [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml).

Comment: I tried with different formats, but it didnt help. I don't know what im doing wrong here. The conversion from vec3 [-1,1] to rgb [0,1] and back looks rights. Is there anything else to consider?

Comment: As rabbid said: Gamma correction will alter your values and that doesn't work with normal map data. You have to use a srgb format or a floating-point format. There has to be some difference when you do that.

Comment: How do you calculate the `normals[]` array in the first place?

Comment: @derhass i have 4 neighbor vertex, so 4 vectors for each vertex. I calculate the crossproduct of 2 enclosing vectors and get 4 face normals. I sum up the 4 normals and do normalize and this is my new vertex normal. For increasing the resolution of the terrain grid I just create a new height as the average of 4 neighbor heights. In the second picture you can see the result of increased resolution.

Comment: @BDL so GL_RGB16F should be fine?

Comment: As you can see on the picture, the normals in the texture are obviously not the same as the vertex ones. They differ greatly in direction. As long as you don't provide the source code which explains the generation of both images, it is impossible to spot the error.

Comment: sorry my fault, i found the mistake. i have two vectors of vertex data, one is filled with unit values and one is filled with the stretched values i want to render and i mixed them together. Nevertheless Thanks for your help guys!